# jupyter -toolbar is invisible

Tags: jupyter, toolbars

I newly downloaded a jupyter and try to use it.
However, with my mac and window computer, 
I cannot see the toolbar in jupyter.

I tried to search to solve this issue and I tried to uninstall every version of python on my computers, both on mac and window one, and reinstall the jupyter.

However, I still see the same problem.
Can someone help me do deal this issue?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Toolbar not visible after setting jupyter notebook theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56044487/toolbar-not-visible-after-setting-jupyter-notebook-theme)

Answer (score 8):

It happened to me as well, and in my case it was much more simple answer. It can be shown/hidden with the "View/Toggle Toolbar" menu.
[View/Toggle Toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpEZC.png)

Answer (score 7):

You're not seeing the toolbar because to Jupyter, you're opening a file. If you want to run Python code, you need to create a new Notebook. This will create an `.ipynb` file, in which Jupyter can run Python code. Jupyter cannot run `.py` files from the web interface.

Comment: Thank you.  That makes sense, it was driving me crazy :)

Answer (score 5):

edit ~/.jupyter/custom/custom.css. I changed the mailtoolbar setting from ’none’ to ‘block’. i.e. find this line:

```
div#maintoolbar {
    display: none !important;
}
```

...and change it to:

```
div#maintoolbar {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
!pip install jupyterthemes
import jupyterthemes as jt

!jt -r
```

this will throw the output like this
Reset css and font defaults in: /Users/malaudeen/.jupyter/custom & /Users/malaudeen/Library/Jupyter/nbextensions

Finally
refresh your browser.

Now:
It can be shown/hidden with the "View/Toggle Toolbar" menu.

Answer (score 0):

this was my problem also. I got a list of python files but no toolbar.
BUT to the extreme right are 3 buttons a reload-symbol and one marked 'new' 
I selected Python 3 and lo and behold the menu appear at the top of the file. 
Loading a  python program into the note book did not reveal the tool bar !

Answer (score 0):

Go to view, you can see Header and toolbar. If you can't see header, click view header and If you can't see toolbar, click view toolbar.