# Toolbar not visible after setting jupyter notebook theme

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, themes, toolbar

The toolbar and notebook name does not show when I call and load the themes from the notebook.

I can load the themes from notebook using a code but I am not sure how to use the switches like `-T` and `-N` for call to toolbar and notebook name.

I have used the following in a code cell:

```
from jupyterthemes import get_themes
import jupyterthemes as jt
from jupyterthemes.stylefx import set_nb_theme
set_nb_theme('solarizedd')
```

The theme changes but the toolbar and notebook name does not appear. Even using the Toggle Header and Toggle Name from view in menu bar has no effect.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**TLDR :**
Run this :

`!jt -t solarizedd -T -N -kl`

*Explanation:*

I just installed the jupyter themes and went thru the same issue. My regular and nbextension toolbar disappeared and could not make it come back unless I reverted to default `!jt -r`.

after some research i fugure it out....so your cell should write

`from jupyterthemes import get_themes import jupyterthemes as jt from jupyterthemes.stylefx import set_nb_theme set_nb_theme('solarizedd', -T, -N,-kl)`

- Toolbar Visible  -T
- Name & Logo Visible  -N
- Kernel Logo Visible  -kl

- their defaults are set to none

see the documentation [documentation of jupyter theme](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes)

or something more permanent and fewer lines of code, using the command "!" in the actual cell

```
!jt -t solarizedd -T -N -kl
```

Comment: `set_nb_theme('solarizedd', -T, -N,-kl)` won't  work (`NameError: name 'T' is not defined` and using`"-T"` etc. will also fail)... `!jt` though works like a charm!:) +1!

Comment: Indeed; `TypeError: set_nb_theme() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given.`

Comment: The first code block (with `set_nb_theme`) in this answer doesn't work, but `!jt -t solarizedd -T -N -kl` does work. Also note `!jt -l` will list all available themes, and screenshots of available themes are available here: https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes/tree/master/screens.

Answer (score 8):

```
jt -t oceans16 -T -N
```

this would surely help.

Comment: How does this answer OP's question? Please explain.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to solve this by editing the custom.css file located at ~/.jupyter/custom/custom.css. I changed the mailtoolbar setting from ’none’ to ‘block’. i.e. find this line:

```
    div#maintoolbar {
        display: none !important;
    }
```

...and change it to:

```
    div#maintoolbar {
        display: block !important;
    }
```

Hope that works for you too!  Don't imagine looking for reasons it failed to start with, however, there is a theory one cannot update while it is running.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to use the code within the notebook itself, you can run it inside the anaconda prompt which is exactly what I did.

Firstly install it using pip:

```
pip install --upgrade jupyterthemes
```

and then run the following line as mentioned by other authors (notice that you cannot use the exclamation mark):

```
jt -t solarizedd -T -N -kl
```

This will apply to all of your notebooks. I find this much cleaner as you don't have to import the library, etc. in each notebook that you use. To apply a different theme replace *solarizedd* with other provided (e.g. *onedork*)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to update to the latest version? I have tried many suggestions. All did not work until I updated the theme package to the latest version

```
pip install --upgrade jupyterthemes
```

I found the solution [here](https://awesomeopensource.com/project/dunovank/jupyter-themes)

Answer (score 1):

```
!pip install jupyterthemes
import jupyterthemes as jt

!jt -r
```

this will throw the output like this
Reset css and font defaults in: /Users/malaudeen/.jupyter/custom & /Users/malaudeen/Library/Jupyter/nbextensions

Finally
refresh your browser.

Answer (score 1):

@jacoM is OP, but I have reasons to believe that the

```
from jupyterthemes import get_themes
```

import jupyterthemes as jt
from jupyterthemes.stylefx import set_nb_theme

and the

```
!jt -t solarizedd -T -N -kl
```

works better when combined!

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps

pip install jupyterthemes #installing jupyter themes

!jt -l   #show list of themes

!jt -t     chesterish -T -N -kl #this will set chesterish as the theme, -T will enable the toggle bar, -N will hide code cell numbers and -kl will show a small kernel logo