# I don't have notebook name and toolbar in jupyter notebook, why?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I saw the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43548091/jupyter-toolbar-is-invisible#:%7E:text=3%20Answers&text=You%27re%20not%20seeing%20the,to%20create%20a%20new%20Notebook.&text=ipynb%20file%2C%20in%20which%20Jupyter%20can%20run%20Python%20code.) . but my problem still remains. Although I make sure that work with `.ipnb` , I don't have toolbar and notebook name?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out [here](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes)!

`!jt -t solarizedd -T -N -kl`